# Need to override Magento\VersionsCms\Block\Hierarchy\Menu.php in M2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Need to override  Magento\VersionsCms\Block\Hierarchy\Menu.php

How i can do that please help

what i tried:

I have created a module in M2

registration.php:-

```
<?php /**  * @license http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)  * @author Hervé Guétin <kensium.guetin@gmail.com> <@kensiumguetin>  * @copyright Copyright (c) 2016 Agence Soon (http://www.agence-soon.fr)  */ \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Kensium_Version',
    __DIR__ );
```

module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Kensium_Version" setup_version="1.0.0"/> </config>
```

di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   <preference for="Magento\VersionsCms\Block\Hierarchy\Menu" type="Kensium\Version\Block\Hierarchy\Menu" /> </config>
```

Menu.php:

```
<?php /**  * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.  * See COPYING.txt for license details.  */ namespace Kensium\Version\Block\Hierarchy;

/**  * Cms Hierarchy Context Menu  */ class Menu extends \Magento\VersionsCms\Block\Hierarchy\Menu {
    protected function _getNodeReplacePairs($node){
        echo 'here';
        exit;

    $label=$node->getLabel();
        $arr=explode(',',$label);
        if(count($arr)>2) return ['__ID__' => $node->getId(), '__LABEL__' => $arr[0], '__CITY__' => $arr[1], '__COUNTRY__' => ','.$arr[2] , '__HREF__' => $node->getUrl()];
        else if(count($arr)>1) return ['__ID__' => $node->getId(), '__LABEL__' => $arr[0], '__CITY__' => $arr[1] , '__COUNTRY__' => '', '__HREF__' => $node->getUrl()];
        else return ['__ID__' => $node->getId(), '__LABEL__' => $node->getLabel() , '__CITY__' => '' , '__COUNTRY__' => '' , '__HREF__' => $node->getUrl()]; } protected function _getLink($node)
    {




        $template = $this->_getData('_link_template');
        if (!$template) {
            $template = '<a href="__HREF__"';
            foreach ($this->_allowedLinkAttributes as $attribute) {
                $value = $this->getData('link_' . $attribute);
                if (!empty($value)) {
                    $template .= ' ' . $attribute . '="' . $this->escapeHtml($value) . '"';
                }
            }
            $template .= '><span>__LABEL__</span></a><span><br>Location :
__CITY____COUNTRY__</span>';
            $this->setData('_link_template', $template);
        }







        return strtr($template, $this->_getNodeReplacePairs($node));
    }

}
```

Comment: remove  di.xml file and try again after clearing cache.

Comment: Try overriding the constructor, and see if you pass through there. My guess is that before the `_getNodeReplacePairs()` function gets called, the original script already fails (probably to retrieve nodes), meaning the function is never called.

Answer (score 0):

This Can Be done Through plugin or preference easily.

Reference
[using plugin and preferences](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/)